# Class methods on Mongoid embedded documents

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I'd like to keep all authentication specific code in the file that defines the Auth "model" like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :auth
  field :username, type: String
end

class Auth
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user, inverse_of: :auth
  field :password

  def self.login(user, pass)
    User.first(conditions: { username: user, password: pass })
  end
end
```

The problem? It's not possible to call class methods of embedded documents:

```
> Auth.login('user', 'pass')
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidCollection: Access to the collection for Auth is not allowed since it is an embedded document, please access a collection from the root document.

> User.auth.login('user', 'pass')
NoMethodError: undefined method `auth' for User:Class
```

Singleton methods in embedded `Mongoid::Document` models is not a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access embedded documents directly like you tried first time `Auth.loggin('user','pass')`. You should be having only instance methods in embedded document models like this

```
def self.login(user, pass)
   User.first(conditions: { username: user, password: pass })
end
```

and can access it by user object like this

```
@user.auth.login('user','pass')
```